# Does the project tango tablet work outdoors?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm looking to develop an outdoor application but not sure if the tango tablet will work outdoors. Other depth devices out there tend to not work well outside becuase they depend on IR light being projected from the device and then observed after it bounces off the objects in the scene. I've been looking for information on this and all I've found is this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5C_HNnW_3Q. Based on the video, it appears it can work outside by doing some IR compensation and/or using the depth sensor but just wanted to make sure before getting the tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sun is out, it will only work in the shade, and darker shade is better.  I tested this morning using the Java Point Cloud sample app, and only get > 10k points in my point cloud in center of my building's shadow, close to the building.  Toward the edge of the shadow the depth point cloud frame rate goes way down and I get the "Few depth points" message.  If it's overcast, I'm guessing your results will vary, depending on how dark it is, I haven't tested this yet.

The tango (yellowstone) tablet also works by [projecting IR light patterns](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116628137365896133358/posts/12pu37m4iMP), like the other depth sensing devices you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can expect the pose tracking and area learning to work as well as they do indoors. The depth perception, however, will likely not work well outside in direct sunlight.