# Maximum range (depth sensor) | Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

I was wondering what the maximum range of the depth sensor on the Project Tango Tablet was.
I can't seem to find it on any of googles pages.

Are there any other limitations to the sensors?

I was wondering, if it was suitable for outdoor use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239932/does-the-project-tango-tablet-work-outdoors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the documentation :

> Current devices are designed to work best indoors at moderate distances (0.5 to 4 meters)

you can get more information on depth [here](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/depth-perception)

Comment: I must be blind..it's in the fourth line of the first paragraph! Thank you very much!

Comment: Its so sad the range is limited to 4 meter. Also this mean that it cannot capture the tress, plants because IR is absorbed  trees, plants. hence I was thinking to make a 3d model of forest so that an accurate biomass can be calculated is not possible. :(